# Swift package manager generate Xcode project while maintaining group structure

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Is it possible to maintain a group structured hierarchy in Xcode when generating from the swift package manager? Every time I run:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

I lose any group (not folder, which works fine) structure I had. I regularly like to have some level of visual organization that is not visible to the code (i.e. groups as opposed to folders) while programming in Xcode.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the same file system structure for your files as you want in the group structure?

Comment: Yes, for instance, to take a crude example, imagine creating a series of separate files with included classes for the following objects: Bird, Fish, Human, all of which reference superclass in a separate file of Living. You might then organize them:
File: Living,
Group: Species
-> File: Bird
-> File: Fish
-> File: Human,
If species was a folder, this would not work with SPM

Answer (score 3):

I believe that what you want is to organize your sources as follows (based on the follow up comment):

`Foo/Package.swift
Foo/Sources/Foo/Living.swift
Foo/Sources/Foo/Specifies/Bird.swift
Foo/Sources/Foo/Specifies/Fish.swift
Foo/Sources/Foo/Specifies/Human.swift`

Note that the important bit here is that if you want to use subdirectories, you have to ensure that your code is all nested one level down inside of `Sources`. This is the convention used when one package declares multiple targets, and it is required if you want to use nesting for sources. See the [source layouts](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#source-layouts) section in the reference.

If you use this layout, then with the latest Swift package manager (available via [swift.org](http://swift.org/download)) the generated Xcode project will have the group structure I believe you want.

This is something we know is confusing right now, and we are evaluating how best to improve things.

Comment: If I do this, then in Xcode after `swift package generate-xcodeproj` then I get what you state, but they are not broken down into groups. The files are all at the same level, but now are named: `Specifies/Bird.swift`, etc. instead of being in the group `Specifies`

Comment: This was something fixed relatively recently in SwiftPM -- to get this behavior you can will need to grab one of the most recent toolchains from http://swift.org